# How to keep scroll position after state update in React Native ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I wont my React Native ScrollView to scroll to the bottom by default. When user scrolls to the top I call API and update the component's state, which causes the component to scroll back to the bottom. I want to keep the current scroll position after the state is updated.

```js
const ifCloseToTop = ({ layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize }) => {
  return contentOffset.y == 0;
};

<ScrollView
  ref={scrollViewRef}
  onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => { 
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({y:0, animated: true }) }} // this is for initial keeping scroll to bottom
  onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (ifCloseToTop(nativeEvent)) {
      handleLoadMore()
      console.log('top')// this function on scroll top api call and state update, but on each update goes to initial bottom position, i want scroll to be current after state update 
    }
  }}
  scrollEventThrottle={400}
>
  <View style={styles.head}>
    // messages
  </View>
</ScrollView>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a ref variable

```
const ScrollViewRef = useRef();
```

then in ScrollView write like this

```
<ScrollView
  ref={ScrollViewRef}
  // onLayout will make sure it scroll to Bottom initially
  onLayout={() => ScrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd()}

  // We don't need `onContentSizeChanged`
  // this onScroll fetches data  when scroll reaches top
  // then it scrolls to last position as you asked

  onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (ifCloseToTop(nativeEvent)) {
      handleLoadMore()
      ScrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
        y: nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height,
        x: 0,
        animated: false,
      });
    }
  }}
  scrollEventThrottle={400}>
      <View style={styles.head}>
         // messages
      </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Don't forget to import `useRef` at the top

```
import {useRef} from "react-native";
```

Working Example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/scroll-view-to-bottom)

Comment: still it not fixed, my issue is when state is  updated with new data, it scroll back automatically to bottom, but i want  scroll to be its current position. should not scroll back to bottom

Comment: Check answer I've updated and check its working in the Snack

Comment: kartikey vaish Thanks working as expected

Comment: @mano Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: kartikey vaish the fix works fine but, is it possible be last data position y-position, the above fix be in last position but not holding data position. i want be in last data position on y .

Comment: I don't understand....Can you please explain a bit clearly?

Comment: when i scroll to top of last data iam doing api call , data appending , the latest data to old data from top. i want scroll position last index of first of load. so from . i can scroll top to see new data. like whatsapp

Comment: Yes, that's how it is implemented in snack

Comment: ScrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
            y:
              nativeEvent.contentSize.height -
              nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height,
          }), this method snak scroll back to bottom again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232022/discussion-between-mano-and-kartikey-vaish).